# Bash Script on Datacenter Subnets with three outputs

Tags: bash, nmap

I've been tasked with finding all Red Hat instances running in our entire datacenter.  This covers roughly thousands of VLANs and IPs.  I've done NMAP for output and tried parsing it into Excel for easier viewing, but... failed.

What I did is create a basic bash script that scans all the IPs from 192.168.*.* to 192.195.*.* -- used those IPs as examples obviously.

```
nmap -F -O 192.168.*.* > /home/knesgoda/results/147.txt
```

Is there a way to run this and get an output that would resemble something like this for easy pivot tabling?

```
IP             Hostname     Operating System
192.168.0.1    host.com     Red Hat Linux
192.168.0.2    host2.com    Windows 10
192.168.0.3    host3.com    OSX 10.10
```

Comment: What does the original output of the command look like? What have you tried to massage it into the form you want? It should probably be a simple `awk` script to rearrange the columns.

Comment: Use [`-oX`](https://nmap.org/book/output-formats-xml-output.html) or [`-oG`](https://nmap.org/book/output-formats-grepable-output.html) for scriptable output. Normal mode changes from version to version.

Comment: `I've been tasked with finding all Red Hat instances running in our entire datacenter` sounds weird. Is this your data center or somebody else's data center? :)

Comment: It currently looks like this:

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-12-17 17:26 PST
Nmap scan report for hostname-dhcp-192-168-0-1.eng.vmware.com (192.168.0.1)
Host is up (0.00042s latency).
Not shown: 94 closed ports
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp   open     ssh
80/tcp   open     http
427/tcp  open     svrloc
443/tcp  open     https
8000/tcp filtered http-alt
8080/tcp open     http-proxy
Aggressive OS guesses: VMware ESXi Server 5.0 - 5.5 (93%), VMware ESXi Server 4.1 (91%), Crestron XPanel control system (90%)
No exact OS matches for host (test conditions non-ideal).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing you could do is use `nmap`'s grep output format:

```
nmap -F -oG output.txt -O 192.168...
```

It isn't exactly what you specified in terms of a report format but it is a lot more like it than the default output format.

To take it to the next level you'll really need to think about learning some sort of scripting language like Python, Perl, Ruby, etc. In that case you might want to use the XML output format (`-oX`) and parse that with a library one of those languages provides.